# Make spots on shapes by clicking on the shape in GOJS

Tags: gojs

I am using GOJS and I want to make a spot whenever I click on the shape .The spot should appear exactly on the position where I clicked on the shape.Can I do that?
here is my code i added the spots or ports hardcoded

```
function makePort(name, spot, output, input) {
      return GO(go.Shape, "Circle",
               {
                  fill: "grey",  
                  stroke: null,
                  desiredSize: new go.Size(10, 10),
                  alignment: spot, 
                  alignmentFocus: spot,  
                  portId: name, 
                  fromSpot: spot, toSpot: spot,  
                  fromLinkable: output, toLinkable: input,  
                  cursor: "pointer"  
               });
    }
 myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
     GO(go.Node, "Spot",
     {

       selectionAdorned: false,  // don't show the standard selection handle
       resizable: true, resizeObjectName: "SHAPE",  // user can resize the Shape
        rotatable: true, rotateObjectName: "SHAPE",  // user can rotate the Shape
                                                     // without rotating the label
        layoutConditions: go.Part.LayoutStandard & ~go.Part.LayoutNodeSized
      },
      new go.Binding("location", "loc").makeTwoWay(),  // TwoWay Binding // Binds diagram and model location with eachother 
      a = GO(go.Shape,
        {
          click:click1,
          name: "SHAPE",
          width: 70, height: 70,
          stroke: "#000000",
          fill: "transparent",
          //angle: 45,
          strokeWidth: 1
        },
        new go.Binding("figure","fig"),
        new go.Binding("name_shape", "key"),
       new go.Binding("angle", "ang").makeTwoWay(),  // Binds diagram and model angle with eachother 
        // new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size").makeTwoWay(), // Binds diagram and model size with eachother 
        new go.Binding("geometryString", "geometry").makeTwoWay()),// Binds diagram and model geometry string with eachother 
      // GO(go.Shape,"Circle",  // the "A" port
      //       { width: 20, height: 20, portId: "A",stroke:null,toSpot: go.Spot.Left}),
      /*GO(go.Panel, "Vertical",
        GO(go.TextBlock,
          new go.Binding("text", "fig")),
        GO(go.TextBlock, { stroke: "blue" },
          new go.Binding("text", "parameter1", function(p1) { return p1; }).ofObject("SHAPE"))
      )*/
       // GO(go.Shape,  // the "A" port
       //      { width: 6, height: 6, portId: "A" }),

      // four small named ports, one on each side:
        makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
        makePort("TL", go.Spot.TopLeft, true, true),
        makePort("BL", go.Spot.BottomLeft, true, true),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
        makePort("TR", go.Spot.TopRight, true, true),
        makePort("BR", go.Spot.BottomRight, true, true),
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, true),
        makePort("C",go.Spot.Center,true,true),

        { // handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
          mouseEnter: function(e, node) { showSmallPorts(node, true); },
          mouseLeave: function(e, node) { showSmallPorts(node, false); }
        }
    );

     function showSmallPorts(node, show) {
      node.ports.each(function(port) {
        if (port.portId !== "") {  // don't change the default port, which is the big shape
          port.fill = show ? "rgba(0,0,0,.3)" : null;
        }
      });
```

Comment: This is not a very good question is SO. Please do not ask "how can i do this or that.." or "is this possible...". Be more specific. Show us your code an things you allready tried and figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what I think you are asking for:

```
  function init() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
        { initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center, "undoManager.isEnabled": true });

    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Spot",
        { selectionObjectName: "BODY" },
        new go.Binding("itemArray", "spots"),
        { // each spot is represented by a Panel holding a circular Shape
          // at a particular alignment relative to the "BODY"
          itemTemplate:
            $(go.Panel,
              $(go.Shape, "Circle",
                {
                  fill: $(go.Brush, go.Brush.Radial, { 0.0: "gray", 1.0: "transparent" }),
                  strokeWidth: 0, width: 16, height: 16
                }),
              new go.Binding("alignment", "spot", go.Spot.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Spot.stringify)
            ),
          // when the user clicks on the node, add a "spot"
          click: function(e, obj) {
            e.diagram.startTransaction();
            // convert click point into Spot in node's bounds
            var pt = e.documentPoint;  // in document coordinates
            var node = obj.part;
            var b = node.actualBounds;  // will be in document coordinates
            var spot = new go.Spot(Math.max(0, Math.min((pt.x - b.x) / b.width, 1)),
                                   Math.max(0, Math.min((pt.y - b.y) / b.height, 1)));
            // add an Object describing the spot's location (as a Spot value)
            var spotsArray = node.data.spots;
            if (!Array.isArray(spotsArray)) spotsArray = node.data.spots = [];
            e.diagram.model.addArrayItem(spotsArray, { spot: go.Spot.stringify(spot) });
            e.diagram.commitTransaction("added spot");
          }
        },
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
          { name: "BODY", width: 100, height: 100 },
          $(go.Shape, { fill: "whitesmoke" }),
          $(go.TextBlock, { editable: true },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        )
      );

    myDiagram.model = $(go.GraphLinksModel,
      {
        copiesArrays: true,  // make sure the data.spots Array is copied
        copiesArrayObjects: true,  // make sure the Objects in those Arrays are also copied
        nodeDataArray: [
          { key: 1, text: "Alpha", spots: [] },
          { key: 2, text: "Beta", spots: [{ spot: "0.3, 0.2" }] }
        ],
        linkDataArray: [
          { from: 1, to: 2 }
        ]
      });
  }
```

Executing this and clicking on the nodes in a few places results in:
[image: Two nodes with some spots added by clicking on them]

Note that the "Beta" node starts off with a spot, as defined in the model data.

By the way it wasn't clear to me that the "spots" the user wants to add really had to be "ports".  You can make each "spot" a "port" by giving it a unique **GraphObject.portId**.

You might want to read all of the pages of the GoJS Introduction, at http://gojs.net/latest/intro.

Comment: Thank you so much it works like a charm.I am getting the spots on the mouse click location.But i am not able to connect them with a link as i was doing in the previous code. Because there i gave them a name and assigned this to  portId: name .There i was getting the name from    makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
 makePort("TL", go.Spot.TopLeft, true, true)
Here name of ports are T,L,TL.
Now i am not able to connect the spots because i dont have a name or id of the spots (portId:" ").So i am able to connect only two spots.